# App Clip scanning works with app installed and without app with activity in scene delegate, but how do I get the appclip if the app is in background?

Tags: swift, apple-appclips

I already published my appclip and the app to the store. But now I found out that if the app is open in the background the activity for userActivities didn't get called.

I used this in the scene delegate:

```swift
scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    for activity in connectionOptions.userActivities where activity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb { appClipCodeURL = activity.webpageURL }
```

What should I call or where can I get the appclip link if the app is open in the background to scan another appclip with a different URL?

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity) {
    if userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb {
        appClipCodeURL = userActivity.webpageURL
        print(appClipCodeURL)
    }
}
```